# How to make a simple navigator - content menu

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

Attached is the code snippet of my  navigator

```
<!-- Navigator -->
<div style="position:abolute;top:50px" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <ul id="yw0" class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="<?php $this->renderPartial("company",false); ?>" style="color:black">Company</a></li>
                <li><a  style="color:black" href="#"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>&nbspFAQs</a></li>
                 <li><a  style="color:black" href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>&nbspHelp Center</a></li>
                 <li><a  style="color:black" href="#"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>&nbspPress</a></li>
                <li><a  style="color:black" href="#">Careers</a></li>
                   <li><a  style="color:black" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>&nbspContact Us</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
<!-- Content -->
```

I am actually trying to put a logic that whenever I click on a link , it should renderPartial the appropriate file and also highlight the menu below the navigator..   I tried doing the following 
 `<a href="<?php $this->renderPartial("company",false); ?>"` 
But I guess it is not the right way.. dunno how can I achieve it?

Comment: First thing is you are doing in completely wrong, if you can tell us where you want to render the content may be we can help

Comment: @yiiframe I just want to create a menu, (vertical or horizontal) and when clicked on any of the menu items, I would like to "renderPartial" the contents without going to the controller. it could be as simple as creating a tab.. i tried the code above but was really confused

Comment: you said you want to render partial the content where you want to render that content ? in anchor tag of nav link you can only bind an event to show or hide the content

Comment: updated the answer as per your requirments

Comment: you are awesome!!! this is what I needed.. but again, the menu items dont get active automatically..

Comment: @yiiframe Do you know how can I dynamically change the active items? the class="active" is always active

Comment: updated ShowData function in answer to change active item (code is not tested)

Comment: GREAT!! but actually i have to tell you tht the class is in the <li tag> so i had to change it to $('.nav li').removeClass('active'); in that way the current class disappears but then  $(this).addClass('active'); does nothing..

Comment: The links are not getting active actually here is my function :

Comment: <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
         showData('company');

    });

  function showData(id) {
   
           $('.renderContent').hide();
            $(this).add('li.active').toggleClass('active');
          $('#'+id).show();   
        }

      $('.renderContent').hide();
  </script>

Comment: code shared by you in comment is not Ok for your requirments, check showData function in answer(updated)

Comment: Thanks @yiiframe !!! Everything works fine now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will go into your view file

```
    <!-- Navigator -->
    <div style="position:abolute;top:50px" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <ul id="yw0" class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" onclick="showData('company')" style="color:black">Company</a></li>
                    <li><a onclick="showData('user')"   style="color:black" href="#"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>&nbspFAQs</a></li>
                     <li><a  style="color:black" href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>&nbspHelp Center</a></li>
                     <li><a  style="color:black" href="#"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>&nbspPress</a></li>
                    <li><a  style="color:black" href="#">Careers</a></li>
                       <li><a  style="color:black" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>&nbspContact Us</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
    </div>

<div class="main-content">
    <div id="company" class="renderContent">
       <?php $this->renderPartial("company",false); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="user" class="renderContent">
       <?php $this->renderPartial("user",false); ?>
    </div>
<!--- for every menu item there should be a view rendered here--->
</div>
    <!-- Content -->
```

this will go into your js

```
function showData(id) {
    $('.renderContent').hide();
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#'+id).show();
}
$('.renderContent').hide();
```